# python Exit handler dont work probebly when program resolve DNS

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, resolve

I wrote a program to resolve SubDomain using DNSPython library.
When the program is run and the sub domain resolved I write the exit handler to handle <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> signals:

```
def exitHandler(signum = 0, frame = 0):
    print("Kill Process..")
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
    sys.exit(0)
```

If the user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> the program doesn't terminate immediately and in some case the program gets locked!
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You try to kill the process from inside itself? That seems unnecessary. Did you find this code somewhere, I would like to know the rationale.

Comment: Signal handlers in python are only run by the interpreter at safe points between python opcodes. If your program is stuck inside some C code or an uninterruptable sys call, the handler will not run until control returns to the man interpreter loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Ctrl-C on a Python process, it will end.  There's no need to write your own exit handler, and there's certainly no need to try to kill your own process and then call `sys.exit`.  This seems (literally) like over-kill.

Comment: i call my exit handler using this code :signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exitHandler).i comment code and run program..when i press ctrl+c program crash....

Comment: @JesonPark: you'll need to explain why you wrote the handler in the first place, since Python will exit when you type Ctrl-C, and you'll need to provide details of "crash" in this case, if you want more help.

Comment: @NedBatchelder:sir i write program for resolve sub domain of websites..program take one argument(address of websites) and print subdomain of website that take form argument...now suppose after run program,program print 10 subdomain of website's that have 100 subdomain...how can i terminate program to prevent to continued resolve domain..

Comment: @JesonPark: You press ctrl-c. If it doesn't exit then, the program was in an uninterruptable state and didn't listen to signals. Adding a signal handler will not help, as it will not be executed. (Now if you are using sub-processes or threads it may be a different issue).

Comment: now! what do i do?? i think program go to another thread(in dns.resolver.Resolver()) .hance ctrl + c not work for me!